# "The project does not have a build script" error

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, build-script

I am using Net Beans (v8.0.2.) Previously there was no such problem in this project but after working a few hours on my project I tried to test it as a jar again. I pressed "clean and build" and I received "the project does not have a build script" error.[image]

I don't have any idea why this happens. How can I fix this problem?

Please note that the program works correctly when I press "Run Project".

Comment: Restarting my pc solved the problem. I still want to know did why this happen

Answer (score 6):

You have delected the file Build.xml in you projects home direct
it's mostly found in

`C:\users\<yourUsername>\Documents\NetBeansProjects\<yourProjectName>\build.xml`

restarting netbeans solves this problem easily.

you wasted time restarting you PC.